# Control resizing on mouse move or mouse drag

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a simple program, using Excel VBA, that will allow me to resize a control at run-time as the mouse moves or on mouse drag. However, it seems that I'm getting a different result

I'm not sure why I am getting a different final width result, but here's how I'm doing it:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As 
    Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    initialx = X
    initialy = Y
    xmove = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As 
    Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim newx, newy As Single

    If xmove = True Then
        newx = Math.Abs(X - initialx)
        newy = Math.Abs(Y - initialy)
        TextBox1.Width = TextBox1.Width + newx
    End If
End Sub
```

And here's how my form looks like:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the width of the TextBox should increase by 9 as it is the distance covered by the mouse cursor from the mouse cursor initial click(location) on the control.

And I'm stuck with this. Why isn't it working as expected?

Comment: Every time the mouse move fires, you increment the size of the textbox, even if you've *already* resized it from previous moves (so the current width is already more than the original width)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with me, but I've never thought of that. It is now working as expected. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem - it's much easier figuring out *other people's* problems than your own!

Comment: that is what is called a `logic` error.  .... usually very hard to find, because the code is "correct" as far as your mind thinks and the compiler sees no error.

Comment: tip: ... you may already know this, .... but if you don't, read the value of Shift. it reports the state of the shift key. that way you can do resizing only when the shift key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

It's needs Global variable initialWidth.

```
Dim initialX, initialY, xmove, initialWidth
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As _
    Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    initialX = X
    initialY = Y
    initialWidth = TextBox1.Width '<~~setting initialWidth
    xmove = True
    TextBox2.Value = initialX
    TextBox3.Value = initialY
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As _
    Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim newx, newy As Single

    If xmove = True Then
        newx = Math.Abs(X - initialX)
        newy = Math.Abs(Y - initialY)
        'TextBox1.Width = TextBox1.Width + newx
        TextBox1.Width = initialWidth + newx
        TextBox5.Value = newx
        TextBox6.Value = newy
    End If
End Sub
```